freeipa list all system accounts
How using ldapsearch list all sysaccounts?
I try something (unsuccessfully):
ldapsearch -x -b "dc=example,dc=com" -H ldap://ipa.example.com -D \
"uid=myuser,cn=sysaccounts,cn=etc,dc=example,dc=com" -W "(uid=*,cn=sysaccounts)" dn

But, if I search normal users, it's ok:
ldapsearch -x -b "dc=example,dc=com" -H ldap://ipa.example.com -D \
"uid=myuser,cn=sysaccounts,cn=etc,dc=example,dc=com" -W "(uid=*)" dn

Maybe my filter is bad..

You could use this filter (&(uid=*)(cn=sysaccounts)) with the base search (-b option) dc=example,dc=com, or, if all sysaccounts have their dn structured as uid=<uid>,cn=sysaccounts,cn=etc,dc=example,dc=com, just narrow the base search to cn=sysaccounts,cn=etc,dc=example,dc=com.

Unfortunately it didn't help. It returned "result: 0 Success"
